# Using GroupBy for Multiple Columns and Returning List<TSource>

Tags: c#

In this [**article**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935264/group-by-with-multiple-columns-using-lambda) it shows how we can group multiple columns in a lambda expression. However it returns an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>>` and that is not the result that I want to achieve.

I created a class which contains a few properties.

```
internal class Class1
{
    internal string prop1 { get; set; }
    internal string prop2 { get; set; }
    internal decimal? prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I create the following lambda expression, it returns an `IQueryable<IEnumerable<Class1>> listClass1`

```
var listClass1 = context.Table1
    .Join(context.Table2,
            t1 => t1.Id,
            t2 => t2.Table1Id,
            (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
    .Where(/*some expressions here*/)
    .GroupBy(data => new
    {
        data.t1.Column1,
        data.t2.Column2,
    })
    .Select(data => data.Select(x => new Class1
    {
        prop1 = x.t1.Column1,
        prop2 = x.t2.Column2,
        prop3 = x.t1.Column3
    }));
```

But what I want to have is a **`List<Class1> listClass1`** because I am planning to use `foreach` to iterate each element in the list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you shouldn't use a `GroupBy()`. The goal of a `GroupBy()` is to split a single list of items into multiple lists of items.
The distribution of the items happens based on equal key values. In your case, the key consists of more than one column, but the principle remains the same.

`SelectMany()` is the opposite of `GroupBy()`. It creates a single list out of multiple different lists.

The direct answer to your question is that you should change your `Select()` into a `SelectMany()`. That does exactly what you want it to.

---

But that's not the best solution for your case. It is completely pointless to do `GroupBy().SelectMany()`, since these operations cancel eachother out!

```
var listClass1 = context.Table1
    .Join(context.Table2,
        t1 => t1.Id,
        t2 => t2.Table1Id,
        (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
    .Where(/*some expressions here*/)
    .Select(x => new Class1
        {
            prop1 = x.t1.Column1,
            prop2 = x.t2.Column2,
            prop3 = x.t1.Column3
        });
```

---

**Edit** from your comment below, I can see that you are using a group by as a way to get distinct values (no double rows that are fully equal)

This can be done by using the `Distinct()` method:

```
var listClass1 = context.Table1
    .Join(context.Table2,
        t1 => t1.Id,
        t2 => t2.Table1Id,
        (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
    .Where(/*some expressions here*/)
    .Distinct() //filters out all the double entries
    .Select(x => new Class1
        {
            prop1 = x.t1.Column1,
            prop2 = x.t2.Column2,
            prop3 = x.t1.Column3
        });
```

[I refer you to this SO question that addresses when to use DISTINCT or GROUP BY.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)
The principle is the same both for SQL and LINQ, since LINQ tries to emulate how SQL works.

Comment: So how can I convert the following SQL statement to a lambda expression? The results in this query is the one I am trying to achieve.

`SELECT t1.Column1, t2.Column2, t1.Column3
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
 INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1Id
WHERE --some expressions
GROUP BY t1.Column1, t2.Column2, t1.Column3`

Comment: `SELECT t1.Column1, t2.Column2, t1.Column3 ... GROUP BY t1.Column1, t2.Column2, t1.Column3` is functionally equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT t1.Column1, t2.Column2, t1.Column3 ...` You should only use grouping if you actually want an aggregate function to be used, **e.g.** counting how many people live in every city would be `Select CityName, Count(*) from Citizens group by CityName`. You are not calling an aggregate function, and therefore have no need to use group by.

Comment: Your edited answer solved my problem! So it is clear to me now the difference between the two. I should have used DISTINCT instead. Thank you! I will mark this as an answer.