# How to Create a List<TSource> for Razor-generated .cshtml files

Tags: c#, razorgenerator

In relation to my previous **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302244/using-groupby-for-multiple-columns-and-returning-listtsource/44302443?noredirect=1#comment75610315_44302443)**, I want to set the returned `List<Class1> listClass` in my .cshtml file. However, I cannot create the following code in the .cshtml file since it does not recognize the **Class1** class:

```
@ { 
    List<Class1> listClass = new List<Class1>();
}

<html>
    <!-- code for the view goes here -->
</html>
```

**Class1** and the **.cshtml** file are located in different namespaces. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about add a using in your cshtml file: `@using MyNamespace`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import a namespace in Razor View Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the namespace your Class1 is located in, in a `@using` statement

[How do I import a namespace in Razor View Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page)