# Lambda : GroupBy multiple columns where one of them is DbFunctions.TruncateTime()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, group-by, asp.net-mvc-5

**NOTE** : This is NOT a duplicate of this [useful SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935264/group-by-with-multiple-columns-using-lambda), my problem is all about the `TruncateTime` inside the `GroupBy` clause. See explanations below :

I'd like to use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` in a multiple `GroupBy` clause, but it doesn't seem to work in my ASP.NET MVC5 project.

Here is a first lambda I wrote, it gives me the total number of views per day for a set of data.
It gives me the expected result :

```
var qViews = dbContext.TABLE_C.Where(c => c.IdUser == 1234)
            .Join(dbContext.TABLE_V.Where(v => v.Date > DbFunctions.AddMonths(DateTime.Now, -1)), c => c.Id, v => v.Id, (c, v) => new { c, v })
            .GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.v.MyDateTimeColumn))
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Date = (DateTime)g.Key,
                NbViews = g.Count(),
            }).ToDictionary(p => p.Date, p => p.NbViews);
```

Result is something like that :

> ...
>   Date            | Views
>   03/07/2018  |   15
>   03/08/2018  |   8
>   03/09/2018  |   23

Now, I'd like a more detailled result, with the number of views per day AND PER ITEM on the same set of data.

Here is what I'd like to write :

```
var qViews = dbContext.TABLE_C.Where(c => c.IdUser == 1234)
            .Join(dbContext.TABLE_V.Where(v => v.Date > DbFunctions.AddMonths(DateTime.Now, -1)), c => c.Id, v => v.Id, (c, v) => new { c, v })
            .GroupBy(x => new { DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.v.MyDateTimeColumn), x.c.Id})  // Issue #1
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Date = g.Key.Date,  //Issue #2
                NbViews = g.Count(),
            }).ToDictionary(p => p.Date, p => p.NbViews);
```

And I **expected** something like that :

> ...
>   Date            | Views | ID Item
>   03/07/2018  |   4      | 456789
>   03/07/2018  |   11    | 845674
>   03/08/2018  |   6      | 325987
>   03/08/2018  |   1      | 548965
>   03/08/2018  |   1      | 222695
>   03/09/2018  |   23    |  157896

So, this request have two issues (see comments above)

**Issue #1** : It seems I can't `GroupBy` multiple columns, which one of them use `DbFunctions`. If I use `.GroupBy(x => new { x.v.MyDateTimeColumn, x.c.Id })`, code compiles, but doesn't give me the expected result, as I want to group by date, not date + time

**Issue #2** : `Date = g.Key.Date,` seems wrong for the compiler. When I wrote `g.Key`, autocompletion only suggests me the `Id` column, but it doesn't see the truncated date.

Why can't I `GroupBy` multiple columns, with one of them is a truncated Date ?
Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Doesn't x.v.Date just return Date without time? At least according to MSDN DateTime.Date returns the Date component of a DateTime object. I'm just curious, that's why I ask.

Comment: This is a bad name of mine, Date is the name of my SQL column, which is a `DateTime` (i will rename it as `MyDateTimeColumn`)

Comment: no worries, that clears up my question though.

Comment: What happens if you do x.v.MyDateTimeColumn.Date in GroupBy

Comment: Pleas try: `new { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.v.MyDateTimeColumn), Id = x.c.Id}` and use that during projection.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Seems better, I have an exception `Element with same key has already been added`. I'm investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your anonymous type's properties names if you want to use them later on:

```
.GroupBy(x => new 
              { Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.v.MyDateTimeColumn),
                Id = x.c.Id
              })
```

Then you can project on that:

```
.Select(g => new
{
    Date = g.Date,  
    NbViews = g.Count(),
})
```

And finally you cannot do this:

```
.ToDictionary(p => p.Date, p => p.NbViews);
```

because you will get this error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

Why? Because the `Date` is not unique since you just grouped by `Date` and `Id` so `Date`(s) will be duplicated. It is the same as this but this is a list of `string`:

```
var nums = new List<string> { "1", "1", "1", "2" };
nums.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);
```

But, perhaps, you may want to do this:

```
var lu = nums.ToLookup(x => x, x => x);
```

And now you can look them up:

```
// Returns 3 items since there are 3 "1"s
IEnumerable<string> ones = lu["1"];
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, but it's still unclear for me... I keep getting this error. Is it because the name of `MyDateTimeColumn` is actually `Date`, so there is a duplication during the projection ?

Comment: @AlexB No you are getting it because you are grouping based on 2 things: `Date` and `Id`. Therefore, you will have duplicate `Date`(s): Look at your table just before Issue #1 in your question. If `Date` are duplicated, how can you make them the `Key` in your dictionary?

Comment: Ok, I guess I understand now ! So basically, how can I workaround that ? I don't really care about the `Dictionnary` type, this is a method of my Data Access Layer. Is there any type more appropriated ?

Comment: @AlexB Have you read my answer? Did you read the last part about lookups? You just need this: `.ToLookup(p => p.Date, p => p.NbViews);` instead of `ToDictionary(p => p.Date, p => p.NbViews);` [More here](http://www.donnfelker.com/linq-tolookup-vs-todictionary/)

Comment: oops i didn't refresh the page, my bad. Lookup works, thanks a lot ! I never used it before, I will read about it. Thanks a lot :-)