# LINQ select row with max value after group by

Tags: linq, ef-core-3.1

I have following sql statement:

```
Select 
   tsl.Transaction_Id, 
   tsl.State_Id,
   MAX(tsl."Timestamp") 
from TransactionStatesLog tsl 
group by tsl.Transaction_Id
```

How this statement can be translated to LINQ? I just want to select the whole row, where Timestamp is maximum of the group.

With this code i am able just to select `TransactionId` and max `Timestamp` from the group.

```
var states = (from logs in _context.TransactionStatesLog
              group logs by new { logs.TransactionId } into g
              select new
              {
                  TransactionId = g.Key,
                  Timestamp = g.Max(x => x.Timestamp)
              }).ToList();
```

I am working with ef core 3.1

Comment: I cant see how that SQL would work since `tsl.State_Id` is not part of the group by.

Comment: This is Sqlite right? It allows fields in the Select that are on the same aggregation level as the grouping field(s). But LINQ and EF's translation won't allow that, so you have to add `State_Id` to the grouping key, as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you forgot to add `tsl.State_Id` to your SQL as grouping key as follows(otherwise that SQL does not work either):

```
Select 
   tsl.Transaction_Id, 
   tsl.State_Id,
   MAX(tsl."Timestamp") 
from TransactionStatesLog tsl 
group by tsl.Transaction_Id, tsl.State_Id
```

If I understood you correctly you need to add `StateId` to grouping statement as well so that you will be able to select `StateId` and `TransactionId`.

So this should work:

```
var states = (from logs in _context.TransactionStatesLog
              group logs by new { logs.TransactionId, logs.StateId } into g
              select new
              {
                  TransactionId = g.Key.TransactionId,
                  StateId = g.Key.StateId,
                  Timestamp = g.Max(x => x.Timestamp)
              }).ToList();
```

See: [Group by with multiple columns using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935264/group-by-with-multiple-columns-using-lambda/6935416)